# Make PrimeFaces dataTable editable by default

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working on JSF2, PrimeFaces 3. Is there a way to make the dataTable editable by default so the users do not have to click the rowEditor button?

I'm using the dataTable for taking user inputs initially.

Answer (score 4):

Dont Keep rowEditor in the datatable. Have the editable components like inputText and selectOneMenu in the cells. Input and output facet are redundant.

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{bean.list_dtls}" var="dataItem">
    <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
               <h:outputLabel value="Field 1" />
         </f:facet>
         <p:inputText value="#{dataItem.myField}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: it doesn't apply the request values on submit.

Comment: Make sure that listeners on editable components write back the user input into the datatable cells